# Order by timeUpdated, if exists, otherwise timeCreated

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I have 2 fields in an elastic type, namely `timeCreated` and `timeUpdated`. Now my business case is that we should always order by `timeUpdated`, unless it's `null` (or non-existent), which then obviously leaves us with `timeCreated`, which is *always* set.

Now by my understanding of how sorting in elasticsearch works, the following won't work because it'll sort by `timeUpdated` AND `timeCreated` together, and not in the way I'm looking for.

```
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"sort": {
    "timeUpdated": {"order": "desc", "missing": "_last"},
    "timeCreated": {"order": "desc"}
}
```

I'm not really sure whether this is possible or not, but elastic is awesome, so I'm hoping it's a simple thing that I missed in the docs.

I'm using the latest version (1.6 I believe) with PHP using Elastica (though that makes zero difference to the original question).

**EDIT**

As an example, if I have 3 documents:

```
1 - {"timeCreated": "2015-07-08T08:00:00Z"},
2 - {"timeCreated": "2015-05-08T10:00:00Z", "timeUpdated": "2015-07-09T08:00:00"}
3 - {"timeCreated": "2015-07-10T08:00:00Z"}
```

The order it should display in must be `3, 2, 1`. What I'm getting is `2, 3, 1`.

Comment: What you posted should be exactly what you need. It doesn't work?

Comment: @AndreiStefan as far as I understand it, with this approach, the "null" valued docs will be right at the "bottom" of the list, and then that "bottom" section of the "sorting list" will be sorted according to `timeCreated`. If my understanding around this is wrong, I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Ooh, I see now. You need a `script` sorting then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `script` sorting in this case:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "if (doc['timeUpdated'].value != 0) doc['timeUpdated'].value else doc['timeCreated'].value",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! For anyone else who gets errors about inline scripts not being allowed, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-scripting.html helped me out

Comment: Update: In `elasticsearch` 7.3.12. using doc['timeUpdated'].size() != 0 instead.